# How to Update value in MultiValueMap for a specific key

Tags: java, dictionary, apache-commons-collection

I have a MultiValueMap like

```
{3=[c-2, c-2], 2=[b-1, b-1], 1=[a-1, a-2, a-3]}
```

At one point I have to update a single value of a specific key
for example I have to update the key `2` like

```
2=[u-1,u-2]
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used that library - but I would expect these two examples to do what you need:

```
multiMap.getCollection(2).clear();
multiMap.putAll(2, Arrays.asList("u-1", "u-2"));
```

Or

```
Collection c = multiMap.getCollection(2);
c.clear();
Collections.addAll(c, "u-1", "u-2");
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to call `getCollection()` to retrieve the current mapping, `remove(key)` to clear that mapping, iterate the retrieved collection to re-insert values that you want to keep, and/or add the new values.

If you *know* the type of collection used for a mapping (because you've called the constructor that takes `collectionFactory`), you could get the collection and update it directly.